# How do I get all files with .md extension, in all subdirectories, that contain a phrase?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, find

I have a parent folder named 'dev', and inside it are all my project folders. The ReadMe files of these projects contain the app type "type: game", for example. What I would like to do is to:

1. search through all subdirectories of the dev folder to find all the files with *.md" extension
2. then return the names of those directories which contain a .md files with containing the phrase "game"

I've tried piping `find` into `grep` like so:

```
find -type f -name "*.md" | grep -ril "type: game"
```

But it just returns the names of files from all subdirectories which contain the phrase "game" in any file.

Comment: You're looking for the [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) command: `find ... | xargs grep ...`

Comment: Or just drop the `find` command and run `grep --include '*.md' -ril "type: game"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find . -type f -name "*.md" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il "type: game" | sed -e 's/[^\/]*$//'`

This finds any files in the current directory and sub-directories with names ending with .md, then greps for files containing the string. We then use sed to trim the filename leaving only the directories containing a file ending in .md with the "type: game" inside.